# Отображение js android

Tags: javascript, android

Надо сделать приложение на андроид, которое бы при просмотре сайта (одного определенного, заранее известного) отображало бы js на нем только по "белому списку", или наоборот, не отображало из черного списка, тут не важно, что легче в реализации.
Соответственно вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы приложение загружало сайт и отфильтровывало по соответствующим спискам js, и какие-то грузило, какие-то нет.

Comment: Думаю нужно назначить `WebViewClient` с переопределёнными методами [`shouldInterceptRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) - они обрабатывают запросы ресурсов, здесь их и можно отфильтровать.

Comment: @woesss а можно поподробнее? Желательно с пояснением в виде кода, заранее спасибо